# Using a button to create a custom class instance and show it in an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstableview

Im stuck on this problem and it's driving me crazy. What I am attempting to do is have a button click create an instance of a custom class, set it's variables, add it to an `NSMutableArray`, and display it in a table view. So far it seems that I have everything working except having the info display in the table view.

My custom class `TradePaperback` just has three `NSString` properties: `title`, `volume`, and `publisher`.

Here is the code for my header and implementation files:

Header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tradeArray;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;

- (IBAction)addTrade:(id)sender;


@end
```

implementation file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "tradePaperback.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(NSMutableArray *)tradeArray{
    if (!_tradeArray){
        _tradeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        TradePaperback *avengers = [[TradePaperback alloc]init];
    avengers.title = @"Avengers";
    avengers.volume= @"volume 01";
    avengers.publisher = @"Marvel Comics";
        [_tradeArray addObject:avengers];}
    return _tradeArray;}

- (IBAction)addTrade:(id)sender {
    TradePaperback *newTrade = [[TradePaperback alloc]init];
    newTrade.title = @"New Trade";
    newTrade.volume = @"Volume Number";
    newTrade.publisher = @"publisher";
    [_tradeArray addObject:newTrade];
    NSLog(@"added");
    NSLog(@"number of items in array is %ld", _tradeArray.count);
    [_tableView reloadData];}

@end
```

My table view is hooked up using bindings. It seems that everything is hooked up correctly since the `avengers` instance of `TadePaperback` that i put in shows up when I run the program. As I click the add button I can see from the log in the console that the array is having items added to it, but they just won't display.

Why would the tableView show the first item in the array, but none of the rest?

Here is a picture of the program after running and clicking the add button a couple of times.

[program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgvJy.png)

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice you guys could give. Thanks in advance.

-Jack

Comment: If you're using bindings to populate your table-view I assume there's an ``NSArrayController`` instance somewhere in the set up; is this the case? If it is, why aren't adding your newly created objects to the table view via the array controller's dedicated ``add...`` or ``insert...`` methods?

Comment: Yes there is an `NSArrayController`. How would I go about using the `add:` or `insert:` methods to do what I'm trying to accomplish with my `-(IBAction)addTrade:(id)sender` method?

Comment: These methods are pretty self-explanatory - what have you tried? I  mostly use the ``insert`` methods that require an insert location as well as an object. Replace your ``_tradeArray addObject:`` call with a call to ``insertObject:atArrangedObjectIndex:`` and see how you get on.

Comment: Yes! This 100%. Everything is working perfectly now. Created an `NSArrayController` Outlet and linked it to my controller in the interface builder. Used the `insertObject:atArrangedObjectIndex:` method you suggested and it's up and running. Thanks a lot man, if you post you comment as an answer I'll select it and give you the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bindings to populate a table view, you're almost certainly using an `NSArrayController` to manage the table's content. If you want to add an object to the array controlled by this controller (your `tradeArray` object), you should do so indirectly: add to the array controller, which will in turn update your array. `NSArrayController` provides a number of `add...` or `insert..` methods; decide which one suits you best, and use it to replace your call to `[_tradeArray addObject:...]`.

The reason this approach works, and yours doesn't is because this engages the key-value coding/observing machinery that underpins bindings. Your approach essentially adds the object *behind the array controller's back* - it's not KVO/KVC-compliant, so the array controller remains unaware of the change. Cocoa *does* provide you with a way of editing the original array in a KVO/KVC-friendly manner if you so wish, it's just a little more work: try the code below, then read Apple's [`NSKeyValueCoding` Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/mutableArrayValueForKey:) and their [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) for an explanation:

```
// Instead of [_tradeArray addObject:newTrade];
[[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"_tradeArray"] addObject:newTrade];
```